# Are there alternatives to Gvim for a GUI for Vim?

Tags: gvim

Gvim is odd and ugly. It provides only a minimal GUI wrapper for Vim. Like has been done for Neovim, has anyone made an nicer alternative GUI front-end for Vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Vim and NeoVim don't share the same structure and Vim doesn't have the possibility to have a separate GUI.

Also, it is not necessarily ugly: it all depends on your configuration.